# Route Confusion with Single Action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I am clearly having issue understanding the routes here or trying to achieve which is not possible.

I have this in my `RouteConfig`:

```cs
 routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Explorer",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{prefix}/{value}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Explorer", action = "Index", prefix ="", value = UrlParameter.Optional }
             );
```

And in `Explorer` Controller I have the following:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("Explorer")]
public class ExplorerController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("id/{value}")]
    public ActionResult Import(decimal? importId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Route("text/{value}")]
    public ActionResult Import(string importWindow)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

One of the **ACTION** (Import) has different **PREFIX** such as `window` and `id` but whenever I try to access it (such as `https://localhost/Explorer/Import/window/helloWorld` OR `https://localhost/Explorer/Import/id/200`) it keeps giving me the following error

> The current request for action 'Import' on controller type
> 'ExplorerController' is ambiguous between the following action
> methods: System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
> Import(System.Nullable`1[System.Decimal]) on type
> projectname.Controllers.ExplorerController System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
> Import(System.String) on type projectname.Controllers.ExplorerController

I know it is ambiguous but I have a prefix which should make it non-ambiguous.

What am I doing wrong here and how to achieve this outcome if this is not the right way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `[Route()]` attribute for action methods in the controller class:

```cs
[RoutePrefix("Explorer")]
public class ExplorerController : Controller
{
    // GET: Explorer
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Example: https://localhost/Explorer/Import/id/200

    [Route("Import/id/{importId:decimal}")]
    public ActionResult Import(decimal? importId)
    {
        return View();
    }

    // Example: https://localhost/Explorer/Import/window/helloWorld

    [Route("Import/{text}/{importWindow}")]
    public ActionResult Import(string importWindow)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Define only the `Default` route in the `RegisterRoutes()` method:

```cs
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense, thanks for that